# how to read file and split in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, readfile

If I had a file(like csv, txt...).

[image]

I wish get two array such as

```
Array(Array(1.0,2.0),Array(4.0,5.0),Array(7.0, 8.0),Array(10.0,11.0),Array(13.0,14.0))
```

and

```
Array(3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0)
```

What's the ideal way to do this in scala?

Comment: Do what? What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: I want to read csv or txt file and split these data.
And I wish to get two array like above form.

Comment: It is (at least) a bad taste to ask questions like "how to do X" without showing the slightest hit of effort to solve the problem yourself. This is not a "do my home work for free" site, but rather "help me become even better at what i do" resource.

Comment: Sorry, I can read file to get array, but I don't know how to split two array.
I tried to use while, but still can't do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [@Vitaliy Kotlyarenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967668/vitaliy-kotlyarenko)'s answer, but without using 3rd parties like Spark (Spark is great if your data is large, but an overkill otherwise):

```
val lines: Iterator[String] = scala.io.Source.fromFile("txt.csv").getLines()
val matrix: Array[Array[Double]] = lines.map(_.split(",").map(_.trim.toDouble)).toArray
val twoFirstColumns: Array[Array[Double]] = matrix.map(_.take(2))
val thirdColumn: Array[Double] = matrix.map(_(2))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("1.csv").map(_.split(',').map(_.trim().toDouble))

rdd.map(_.take(2)).collect()
res0: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(1.0, 2.0), Array(4.0, 5.0), Array(7.0, 8.0), Array(10.0, 11.0), Array(13.0, 14.0))

rdd.map(_(2)).collect()
res2: Array[Double] = Array(3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0)
```

Comment: I don't see Spark in the OP's question?

Comment: oops, that's happens when you have 2 browser tabs with spark and scala tags open.

Answer (score 2):

You can get both arrays in one go, so that you don't need to traverse the data twice:

```
val (first, second) = {
  io.Source.fromFile(name).getLines
   .map(_.split(",").map(_.toDouble))
   .foldRight(Seq.empty[Array[Double]] -> Seq.empty[Double]) {
      case (Array(x, y, z), (as, bs)) => (Array(x, y) +: as, z +: bs)
    }
}
```

Now, you end up with two lists rather that arrays. Of that matters to you, `first.toArray` and `second.toArray` will do the conversion for you.

Comment: Yeah, consider it pseudocode :) I am posting from my phone, so ... caveat emptor. Besides, it just doesn't sit right with me to give complete working code as an answer to questions like this, where the poster is clearly just looking for a way to get someone do their job for them. So, perhaps, a few typos I made are to the best. I hope, the intent and general approach is clear as I outlined it though. @Łukasz

Comment: Allright, I updated the code for you to compile, hope you don't mind.

Comment: They aren't unless you want to paste it into ammonite repl :p